# Area between two curves in terms of x

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I am given two equations and a graph. The equations are

$$x=-y^3+4y+9$$
 $$x=y^2-5y$$

The problem shows a graph with a shaded region, and I am only to find the area above $y=-1$.

I want to set up the equation as this:

$$\int (-y^3 +4y +9) - (y^2 -5y) \,dy$$

However I do not know the exact points of intersection nor how to find them since the equations are in terms of $x$.

Comment: Equate the two functions and solve. i.e $$ -y^3 + 4y + 9 = y^2 - 5y$$ You can find the other point of intersection by using the fact that $y + 3$ is a root of $-y^3 + 4y + 9 - y^2 + 5y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$-y^3+4y+9=x=y^2-5y,$$
so group the $y$'s together on one side of the equation and factor to find
\begin{align*}
0&=y^3+y^2-9y-9\\
&=(y+1)(y^2-9)\\
&=(y+1)(y-3)(y+3).
\end{align*}
The curves therefore intersect at $y=-3$, $y=-1$, and $y=3$.

It's not entirely clear from your question what region you are trying to find the area of, but you might look at
$$\int_{-3}^{-1}\left[(y^2-5y)-(-y^3+4y+9)\right]\,dy$$
and/or
$$\int_{-1}^{3}\left[(-y^3+4y+9)-(y^2-5y)\right]\,dy.$$